# C++ templates avoid passing element type twice

Tags: c++, templates

I have a templated class where I need to pass both the container and the element of the container as template parameters. For example:

```
template<class CONTAINER, class ELEMENT>
class M
{
    void addElement(const ELEMENT e){}
    CONTAINER container;
};
```

so the class would be instantiated like:

```
M<std::array<CustomType, SIZE>, CustomType> m;
```

As you can see, `CustomType` is pass twice.

Is there an elegant way of avoiding this? The problem is I don't know what the container type will be, so that needs to be passed in separately.

Comment: Standard containers have member type `value_type` that can be used to get `ELEMENT` type.

Comment: Use container's value_type attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could suggest two options:

1. Use `value_type` member type that all standard containers have:

   ```
   template<class CONTAINER>
   class M {
       using ELEMENT = typename CONTAINER::value_type;
       // ...
   };
   ```
2. Get element type from some member function. For example:

   ```
   template<class CONTAINER>
   class M {
       using ELEMENT = std::decay_t<decltype(std::declval<CONTAINER>()[0])>;
       // ...
   };
   ```

Answer (score 3):

Standard C++ containers like [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) have a `value_type` member type. So you can use that as the default.

```
template<class CONTAINER, class ELEMENT = typename CONTAINER::value_type>
class M
{
    CONTAINER container;
public:
    void addElement(const ELEMENT e) {}
};

int main() {
    M<std::array<int, 5>> m;
    m.addElement(5);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this :

```
template <template<typename> class CONTAINER , typename ELEMENT>
class M
{
   void addElement(const ELEMENT e){}
   CONTAINER<ELEMENT> container;
};
```

Comment: Yes it works for vector and list  but array should be template<class CONTAINER, class ELEMENT = typename CONTAINER::value_type>

Comment: It is problematic even for `std::vector` and `std::list`, because these templates can have second template parameter to specify an allocator type.